# why maven clean fails when ear is deployed?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-3, ear

I have a weblogic server, on which I've deployed ear using weblogic maven 3.0.5 plugin (weblogic:deploy). Then I'm issuing `mvn clean` and it says that it can't delete `ear` archive, why is that? Why do I need to undeploy ear to be able to remove ear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Checking in my telekinetic powers are working: Is your weblogic running on Windows?

This is because Windows locks files while they're in use and weblogic probably keeps the ear open while the application is running, rather than making a copy of the ear file and using the copy.

I think this answers your question, unfortunately I cannot say how to solve it, as I've run away from weblogic long time ago and promised myself never to return.